# Как сложить цифры введенные из prompt?

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

Как сложить цифры введенные из `prompt()`?

Код JS:

```
var a = prompt("1", '');
var b = prompt("2", '');
var c = a + b;
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы получаете строки, а не числа. Чтобы сложить их как числа, нужно преобразовать их например с помощью функции `parseInt`.

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("1", ''));
var b = parseInt(prompt("2", ''));
var c = a + b;
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще один вариант положу тут:

```js
var a = +prompt("1", '');
var b = +prompt("2", '');
var c = a + b;
alert(c);

// Еще можно так (одним словом, способов много):
// var a = Number(prompt("1", ''));
// var b = Number(prompt("2", ''));
// var c = a + b;
// alert(c);
```

Рекомендую ознакомиться с [преобразованием типов для примитивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion), чтоб данный вопрос был хорошо усвоен и не вызывал в дальнейшем каких-либо проблем.

Answer (score 3):

`promt` возвращает тип данных "строка", перед сложением эту строку нужно преобразовать в число функцией `parseInt` , код должен выглядеть так:

```js
var a = prompt("1", '');
var b = prompt("2", '');
var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

Привести к числу. Например так:

```
var a = prompt("1", '');
var b = prompt("2", '');
var c = +a + +b; // или var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)
alert(c);
```